# Excel Pivot Table: How do I count the number of working days for employees based on date-time values?

Tags: excel, grouping, pivot-table, excel-2013

In my theoretical data set, I have a list which shows the date-time of a sale, and the employee who completed the transaction.

I know how to do grouping in order to show how many sales each employee has per day, but I'm wondering if there's a way to count how many grouped days have more than 0 sales.

---

For example, here's the original data set:

```
Employee | Order Time
    A    | 8/12 8:00
    B    | 8/12 9:00
    A    | 8/12 10:00
    A    | 8/12 14:00
    B    | 8/13 10:00
    B    | 8/13 11:00
    A    | 8/13 15:00
    A    | 8/14 12:00
```

---

Here's the pivot table that I have created:

```
Employee | 8/12 | 8/13 | 8/14
    A    |   3  |   1  |   1
    B    |   1  |   2  |   0
```

---

And here's what I want to know:

```
Employee | Working Days
    A    |      3
    B    |      2
```

Comment: Can't you just use count of date? Meaning you create a new column with only the date an no time. Create the pivot table and set employee vs count of date?

Comment: Using Excel 2013.

The count number used by the count function takes the time into consideration. So, even though I am grouping the numbers by date, the count still uses the raw data (i.e. date + time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your Order Time column (assumed to be `B`) into two, say with Text to Columns and Space as the delimiter (might need a little adjustment). Then pivot (using the Data Model) as shown:

[image: SO38925401 example]

and sum the results (outside the PT) such as with:

```
=SUM(F3:H3)
```

copied down to suit.

Columns F:G may then be hidden.

I fully support @Andrea's Comment (a correction) on the above:

> I think this could have been made simpler. If you remove the "Time" in values of the pivot table and then move "Order" from columns to values and use distinct count as in the example. It should count Employee per date making the sum not needed. If you scale this to make it larger. Say 50 dates then the =Sum() needs to be moved each time.

Comment: I think this could have been made simpler. If you remove the "Time" in values of the pivot table and then move "Order" from columns to values and use distinct count as in the example. It should count Employee per date making the sum not needed. If you scale this to make it larger. Say 50 dates then the `=Sum()` needs to be moved each time.

Comment: I went to sleep after posting my comment. That is why I didn't post. I first wanted to know if the helper clumn (date-time split) was OK with asker.